# Draw random points

Tags: opengl

I have a window size {0,0},{1e6,1e6}. I have created grids of 1000*1000 within this area.
I am trying to create random points in this area.

```
glEnable( GL_POINT_SMOOTH );
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glPointSize( 200 );
for( int i = 0; i < 1e6; i++ )
{
    glColor3ub(0,255,0);
    // width and height are 1e6.
    int x = rand() % WIDTH; 
    int y = rand() % HEIGHT; 
    glBegin( GL_POINTS );
    glVertex2i( x, y );
    glEnd();
}
glFlush();  
glDisable( GL_BLEND );
```

x and y are random numbers. However, all points are drawn only in left bottom of the   window.

Comment: Did you call glViewport? What were the arguments to it? You're viewport might not be the rectangle (0, 0)->(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

Comment: I have passed the actual width and height. Random numbers generated i guess are too small so they are appearing only in the bottom left corner. I want evenly distributed points. Could you please tell me if there is any better approach?

Comment: I want to generate 1000000 points

Comment: I gave some example code below. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: x = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
     y= rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
     discs[i].x=x*WIDTH;
     discs[i].y=y*HEIGHT;Thank you so much. With this code it worked

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `RAND_MAX` on your platform is greater than `1e6`.  Otherwise the largest x/y value you will see will be `RAND_MAX-1`, not `1e6` as you're expecting.

Or generate random numbers [without modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340729/how-do-you-generate-a-random-double-uniformly-distributed-between-0-and-1-from-c).