# How to generate random number betwen 0 and 2pi?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you generate a random double uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340729/how-do-you-generate-a-random-double-uniformly-distributed-between-0-and-1-from-c)

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a random number between 0 and pi, but the usual method won't work because mod does integer division:

```
double num = rand() % 2*M_PI;
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `fmod` in `math.h`, but you might be better off by doing something like `2*M_PI * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1)`.

Comment: I actually saw that before posting this, but wasn't completely sure how it would translate into going to pi.  I've got it now.  Thanks.

Comment: Why is C-related questions closed with C++-related duplicate? The question is still here: how to get uniform distributed double/float value in *[0, 1)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate a random number between 0 and 1, and then multiply the result by `2*M_PI`.

If you have a uniform distribution between 0 and 1, you will also have a uniform distribution between 0 and `2*M_PI`, to the limit of precision available in the numeric type you are using.

For generating a random uniform double between 0 and 1, see the [answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340729/how-do-you-generate-a-random-double-uniformly-distributed-between-0-and-1-from-c) by @dasblinkenlight in his comment.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I saw the thread explaining how to generate a random number between 0 and 1 previously, but didn't realize it was as easy to translate over to pi as simply multiplying.