# C++: High Precision Random Double Numbers

Tags: c++

This is a follow up question on an answer on this page:

[How to generate random double numbers with high precision in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18131869/3199911)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>    

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());

   std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(1, 10);

   for( int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << dist(e2) << std::endl ;
   }

  return 0 ;
}
```

The answer works fine but I had a hard time to realize how to put the output of this code in a double variable instead of printing it to `stdout`. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `some_variable = dist(e2);`?

Comment: if I just run "double var = dist(e2);" it just gives 6 digits...

Comment: Then you should show that in the question.  right now it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: hmm... Does the variable still contain the rest digits and std::setprecision(10) just sets how many will std::cout print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting confused between *actual* precision and *displayed* precision - try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>    

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 e2(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(1, 10);

    double v = dist(e2);   // get a random double at full precision

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << v << std::endl;
                           // display random double with 10 digits of precision
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I got a little confused with that, thinking that what the variable contained depended on the setprecision function. Thanks

Comment: No problem - it's a common source of confusion.

Comment: @PaulR I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258164/how-to-prevent-numbers-from-showing-up-in-scientific-notations). If possible can you help me out.