# Is rand() really that bad?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Inspired by [General purpose random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435567/general-purpose-random-number-generation) I decided to perform my own tests to see what was wrong with rand(). Using this program:

```
srand(time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
    std::cout << rand() % 1000 << " ";
}
```

I loaded it up in Octave using the commands:

```
S = load("test.txt")
hist(S)
```

And got this result:

[image: result]

To me the results seem to be pretty uniform. I expected the results to be more skewed. Did I conduct my test wrong?

Comment: rand is mainly bad because: `RAND_MAX` is implementation defined, and for instance on visual studio it is merely 2^16; rand is global, meaning that if someone else other than you call srand it may screw up your code. If you have C++11-compilant compiler, consider using one of its RNGs

Comment: Depending on the implementation, `rand()` can have low entropy on its lower bits. If you did `rand() % 4`, in some implementations this is pretty non-uniform. That's why it's usually recommended (if you use `rand()`) to write `rand() / (RAND_MAX / 4)` in this case.

Comment: *Is rand() really that bad?* YES!

Comment: Although it may seem uniform, you won't get true uniformity for any  interval width other than a power of two. The math is fairly simple..

Comment: @Creris on MSVC `RAND_MAX` is (2^15-1), not 2^16. So you can't even get a 32-bit int with 2 `rand()` calls. The same in Linux when you have to run 2 calls to get a random int

Answer (score 15):

The test in your question doesn't really test for randomness. All it does is ensure that the numbers are uniformly distributed. This is a necessary but not a sufficient condition: there are many other ways in which a random number generator can be deficient.

For example, if I gave your a function that returned the numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., 999 in a loop, it would also pass your test. Yet it would clearly fail any reasonable definition of randomness.

To see how random number generators are tested in practice, take a look at

- http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/nissc-paper.pdf
- http://www.random.org/analysis/
- http://www.random.org/analysis/Analysis2005.pdf

For a discussion of `rand()` specifically, check out [`rand()` Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Answer (score 2):

One important point you aren't considering is how predictable the generated random sequence is. 
When using time() as the randomness seed, if the attacker knows - more or less - when the seed was generated, he can rather easily reproduce your entire random sequence.

This is why a true random source is desired, assuming you use these random numbers for anything security-related.

When security really matters, you further want to get each of your numbers from the true random source, without relying on a PRNG at all. Slower but safer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your purpose, the provided `rand()` is simple for on hand usage with acceptable distribution possibility, it is not designed for encryption purpose, nor physical simulation purpose. If you wanna one encryption level or to do physical simulation, it is not a good choice, and you may have to get a special implementation.
there's no **real** randomness produced by computer programs yet.

Comment: With regards to the last sentence, are you excluding these devices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator?