# rand() : weird behavior

Tags: c++, random

I am doing a numerical simulation of a problem where I need to need to generate a array of N elements with N/2 0s and other 1s initially. With each iteration the array is shuffled and next array elements are chosen randomly from previous iteration until only 0 or 1 remains. I am recording the number of iteration in T number of trials. To generate random integers I am using discard-modulo method using `rand()`  (got the idea from [here](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>    
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <fstream>      
#include <algorithm> 
#include <array>

using namespace std;

//generate random integer between 0 and MAX
int randomn(int MAX);

int main()
{
    const int N = 10000;
    const int T = 100;     //Number of trials

    srand((unsigned)time(0));   

    ofstream writefile ("Observation.out");

    for (int indexT = 0; indexT < T; indexT++) {

        //initializing myArray
        array<bool, N> myArray;
        array<bool, N> newArray;

        auto middle = myArray.begin() + myArray.size() / 2;
        fill(myArray.begin(), middle, false);
        fill(middle, myArray.end(), true);

        int counterIt = 0;  //desired Iteration number

        for (;;) {
            int counterF = 0;
            int randompos = 0;
            bool savedata = true;

            //suffling myArray using Fisher–Yates shuffle
            for (int indexN = N-1; indexN > 0; indexN--) {
                randompos = randomn(indexN);
                savedata = myArray[randompos];
                myArray[randompos] = myArray[indexN] ;
                myArray[indexN] = savedata;
            }           
            //next Iteration
            for (int indexN = 0; indexN < N; indexN++) {
                randompos = randomn(N-1);
                savedata = myArray[randompos];
                newArray[indexN] = savedata;
                if (savedata == false){
                    counterF += 1;
                }
            }

            copy(begin(newArray), end(newArray), begin(myArray));

            //updating Iteration number
            counterIt += 1;

            if ((counterF == 0)|| (counterF == N)) {
                break;
            }

        }

        writefile << indexT+1 <<"\t"<<counterIt <<endl;
    }

    writefile.close();

    return 0;
}

int randomn (int MAX){
    int temp;
    for (;;){
        temp = rand();
        if ( temp < RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX%(MAX+1) ) 
            return temp%(MAX+1);
    }
}
```

The output is pretty interesting. The first few numbers in output (iteration number per trial) differs but then it converges to a oscillation no matter how many times I run it.
Here is two examples of the output :

```
1st run            2nd run
1  28278          1    13583  
2  7754           2    7308   
3  11308          3    22580  
4  5093           4    6307    ** oscillation starts
5  4952           5    42060   
6  5017           6    10485   
7  10400          7    8525    
8  6307   **      8    31061   
9  42060          9    6307   ** 1st period 
10  10485         10   42060  
11  8525          11   10485 
12  31061         12   8525   
13  6307   **     13   31061  
14  42060         14   6307   ** 2nd period 
15  10485         15   42060
```

Now I know that `rand()` is not the best function for the job (better option is  `<rand>` library in c++11).
But how it is converging from **any initial random number** to this exact period
 `6307 - 42060 - 10485 - 8525 - 31061` ?

Observation: The program uses exactly `2^31` random numbers in that period i.e. the cycle of the random number generating function. **But how?**

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Comment: better option in c++ is to use random_device  than <random>
 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device

Comment: [»There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced. In the past, some implementations of rand() have had serious shortcomings in the randomness, distribution and period of the sequence produced.«](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand)  Use Mersenne Twister instead.  If you need random numbers for cryptography, use OpenSSL (or LibreSSL).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is rand() really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440252/is-rand-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand()` shouldn't be used for anything serious. Its quality can be pretty bad.

For example, I did a simulation with it, and I know the exact answer. With `rand()`, the simulation converged to a slightly different number than the exact answer. I replaced `rand()` with something better, and:

- simulation become 3 times faster
- simulation converged to the exact solution.

A common suggestion is to use mersenne twister instead. However, even MT has its [shortcomings](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/testu01.pdf), it doesn't pass the BigCrush test.

However, this simple random generator passes, and very fast ([xorshift128+](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/xorshift128plus.c)):

```
uint64_t s[2]; // seed this

uint64_t next(void) {
    uint64_t s1 = s[0];
    const uint64_t s0 = s[1];
    const uint64_t result = s0 + s1;
    s[0] = s0;
    s1 ^= s1 << 23; // a
    s[1] = s1 ^ s0 ^ (s1 >> 18) ^ (s0 >> 5); // b, c
    return result; 
}
```

Check out http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/, and their newest generator, [xoroshiro128+](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/xoroshiro128plus.c)