# Seeding srand() once yet rand() gives almost indentical results everytime

Tags: c, clion

I'm trying to create a random array of random integers for a minesweeper game in C.

I'm trying to get random numbers from 1 to 64.

At the beginning of the `main()` function I initialize `srand(time(NULL))`.
Later in the program, I use `rand()` in a loop to generate 8 random integers.
In my initial test runs for other features, the numbers were perfectly random but as I ran more tests it started to give out integers 1-7 consistently and one random double-digit integer.
Worth mentioning these tests are done on the Clion terminal.
Is it a problem just because of where I run the program or something else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void eightByEight(int randArr[], int lower, int upper, int size);

int main() 
{
    int i, randNums[8];
    srand(time(NULL));
    eightByEight(randNums,1,64,8);
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", randNums[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void eightByEight(int randArr[], int lower, int upper, int size)
{
    int i,num;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
         num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
         randArr[i] = num;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code you're describing.

Comment: According to [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/srand.3.html) `rand()` (and `srand()`) are obsoleted in their system (because they have poor quality).

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411498/why-does-rand-repeat-numbers-far-more-often-on-linux-than-mac

Comment: please include a [mcve]. Details do matter. The code you posted does not compile

Comment: Your code is still not compilable. Where's `num` defined? And you didn't declare or define `eightByEight()` before it's being used. Either move the function to before main, or write a prototype for it. Besides, choose **only C or C++**, not both. They're different languages and the answer in each will be vastly different

Comment: Can't reproduce, but please copy/paste your *actual* code, not something that you are guessing is like it. Include how you show the values.

Comment: The code should compile now, sorry for all problems caused earlier.

Comment: Are you working with Mac?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Mac.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem using your _posted_ code?

Answer (score 3):

The `time` function gives you the current time in seconds since the epoch.  If you run the program twice in a short period of time, the `time` function will return the same value on both runs and you'll therefore get the same sequence of random values.

Comment: Not sure if it counts as short time but I ran it with some periods of hours or a day inbetween.