# Convert uint32_t to double between 0 and 1

Tags: c++

I have a shamefully naive question: **What is the best way to convert a `uint32_t` to a `double` between 0 and 1?**

My naive way is

```cpp
double myconvert(uint32_t a)
{
    double n = static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() - std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::min());
    return static_cast<double>(a) / n;
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Perhaps I'm old-fashioned, but I find mathematical code with `static_cast<double>` hard to read. I prefer to promote implicitly all the coefficients in a term using `1.0` at the start.

Comment: Hmm. Naïve *and* old-fashioned ... that's pushing it a bit. :-)

Comment: i don't understand the purpose. so you are casting uint32 input into a double then dividing it by 0x41EFFFFFFFE00000 which is the max uint32 cast to a double.

Comment: Note that neither of the casts in the code in the question is needed.

Comment: Does the range include 1.0 or not? If it doesn`t, some minor modification should be made: Assume linear mapping of points on a circle to the range [0,1) or mapping the [0,2pi).

Comment: @Red.Wave Good point, thanks. For me it would include 1.0. But indeed one should take care

Comment: If it is naive or could depend on the purpose. If the uint32 is a random number and the goal is to generate a corresponding random double between 0 and 1 I believe there are less naive algorithms for that which accounts for the rounding of the double to keep the randomness uniform.

Comment: @Forss Indeed, I'm using it to get a random number [0, 1]. I think this post could benefit for your considerations as an answer. It would be great if you would be willing to post one!

Comment: There are a lot of answers for that more specific question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/1340729/3918852 (see e.g. the answer by DarthGizka).

Comment: What do you consider better, in objective terms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::min()` is 0. Although removing the subtraction doesn't improve the generated assembly since it is known at compile time, it can simplify the function.

Another potential improvement is to calculate the complement of the divisor and use multiplication. You might think that optimiser would do that conversion automatically, but that's often not possible with floating point due to strict rules of IEEE-754.

Example:

```
return a * (1.0 / std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());
```

Note that in the division used to calculate the complement, both operands are known at compile time, so the division is pre-calculated.

As you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sTY6T1qWc), GCC does **not** do the optimisation automatically. It does if you use `-ffast-math` at the cost of IEEE-754 conformance

I checked Agner Fog's instruction [tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) and randomly chose Zen3 architecture, and double division has about 3 times greater latency than multiplication.

Comment: Now just replace `std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()` with `uint32_t(-1)`, and re-arrange: `return .0 / uint32_t(-1) * a;`

Answer (score 6):

It is safe to assume that `std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::min()` will be zero (what *unsigned* integer is less than this?), so you can simplify your formula considerably:

```cpp
double myconvert(uint32_t a)
{
    return static_cast<double>(a) / std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`1.0 * a / std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()`

is one way.